# can lines be labelled to make referring to them dynamic?

Tags: listings

I am using the `listings` package to document code in a `LaTeX` document and have `line numbering` turned on to be able to refer to specific sections in the code. Most changes to the code being documented, something that occurs quite frequently, necessarily mess up the references to line numbers in the accompanying text. Is there a way to make these references to line numbers dynamic, i.e. does the `listings` package provide a way of identifying lines with `labels`? I skimmed through the documentation once again, but nothing leaped at me.

Comment: Even if this is not precisely what I want, the answer points me to the right place in the manual, so I'll tick my question off as solved ... but only after a few hours have passed to see what clever comments might come my way.